# Javadoc in Netbeans, combining <pre> and {@code} gives a larger than wanted font

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

In my Javadoc I give an example of how to use my class. Since this is a multi-line example it was recommended on stackOverflow to use a combination of <pre> and      {@code }.

It looks ok within netbeans, but when I generate the javadoc to HTML it's grown in fontsize, and it's no longer in a monospaced font. like this:

[SCREENSHOT](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2328482/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-08%20at%2021.32.04.JPG)

So my question: What can I do to make it appear in the original monospaced font in the generated html too?

I have a bit of trouble pasting the code here, but this is what it looks like. I replaced the code tags with {@code} too but the result is the same.

This is the code: 
[image: code example]

Comment: That's large, but it's definitely monospaced. What's the code of the javadoc comment? Which version of javadoc are you using?

Comment: Should it not be `{@code}`?

Comment: @JBNizet Now that you mention it, yeah it's indeed monospaced; though not the font that I would expect. I've added the code to the example.

Comment: Try using only `<pre>...</pre>`, and not `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`.

Comment: What?!?! That solved it! Thanks a ton! I guess I was so convinced I had to use code that I never tried it without! It looks great now both within Netbeans as in the generated HTML.